# SNMP access with encryption

Tags: snmp, encryption, net-snmp

I'd like to configure my SNMP v3 (NET-SNMP) agent to limited user range with encryption. Could you give me a short hint how to setup encryption with NET-SNMP? Do you have any experiences in using AES/3DES encryption algorithms with NET-SNMP? My NET-SNMP version is 5.6.

Comment: Start [here](http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/Strong_Authentication_or_Encryption).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit your snmpd.conf and add

> rwuser MD5DESUser

stop snmpd and edit your persistent snmpd.conf and add

> createUser MD5DESUser MD5 "The Net-SNMP Demo Password" DES

And finally, here is an authenticated and encrypted request:

> snmpgetnext -v 3 -n "" -u MD5DESUser -a MD5 -A "The Net-SNMP Demo Password" -x DES -X "The Net-SNMP Demo Password" -l authPriv test.net-snmp.org system

source: http://www.net-snmp.org/wiki/index.php/TUT:SNMPv3_Options